# Using android.jar in Java project - RuntimeException Stub?

Tags: java, android

I tried to **include android.jar** into Java project, **remove JRE from Build Path** and run this code. It throws Runtime exception. Why?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.content.ContentValues.<init>(ContentValues.java:5)
    at JarTest.main(JarTest.java:5)

public class JarTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("test", "test");
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

Why is ContentValues used only in Android environment?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The android.jar in the SDK only contains stub implementations of the SDK classes, not the real implementations that are found on the devices (or emulator).  The jar just provides the class metadata so that your apps that reference the SDK classes will build properly.

You can't create any project that references the android.jar that will run outside an Android device.

Comment: @Emerald214 That JRE classes must be in your classpath and they must not be a stub but android specific classes are stubs. They are an skeleton made so you can code and compile your app using a java IDE but the code isn't really there, maybe some of them are not even made in Java.

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find a real build?

Comment: @Janus Troselsen It's a custom binary that only runs on devices. I wouldn't waste time trying to test Android's code but instead mock and stub it assuming that it works. If you must test the output (I can see why you would want to at least make sure that their code is giving you what you expect) then write a set of functional tests around the output of those Android APIs that you can run on the device or in the emulator.

Answer (score 10):

android.jar contains stubs only, enough to let you build your project, as @antlersoft explained.

The Robolectric project http://robolectric.org/ allows you to run tests on your Android code without using a device. They have real builds available on Maven http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.robolectric%22

I have been successfully running most of the Android backend code by using the [android-all](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22android-all%22) artifact.

Might not help in your specific case, since some APIs are still out of bounds, but for most other cases of `java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!` including the artifacts from Robolectric should help.