# jUnit tests work in Eclipse, but fail in ant - java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have unit tests for my project. They run fine in Eclipse  but fail in ant with errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

I've automaticaly generated my ant build.xml from EclipseIDE acording to [this](http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/) article.

My build.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="main" name="MyProjectJavaTest">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="MyProject.location" value="../MyProject"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>

    <path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../../winapl/adt-bundle-windows-x86/eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../../../winapl/adt-bundle-windows-x86/eclipse/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar"/>
    </path>

    <path id="Android 4.2.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="../../../../../winapl/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/platforms/android-4.2/android.jar"/>
    </path>

    <path id="Android Dependencies.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path id="Persisted container [com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES for project [MyProject]].libraryclasspath"/>
    <path id="MyProject.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${MyProject.location}/bin/classes"/>
        <path refid="Android 4.2.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="Android Dependencies.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="Persisted container [com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES for project [MyProject]].libraryclasspath"/>
    </path>

    <path id="MyProjectJavaTest.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <path refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="MyProject.classpath"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/java-json.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/fluent-hc-4.2.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/httpclient-4.2.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/httpcore-4.2.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/httpcomponents/httpmime-4.2.5.jar"/>
    </path>

            <target name="main" depends="MyProjectJavaTest,junitreport"/>

    <target name="MyProjectJavaTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.F1U8GetTermsAndConditions" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.JsonMarshallerTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.ParamsTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP1GetServiceDescriptionTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP2GetServiceDescriptionLogoTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP3GetServiceListTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP4GetServiceLogoTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP5GetSubscribedServiceInformationTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP6GetSubscribedServiceListTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP7SendServiceNotificationTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.TP8SubscribeToServiceTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.WMClientImplAndHMEIntegrationTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <test name="my.android.MyProject.api.WMClientImplTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="MyProjectJavaTest.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>
```

ant version: 1.9.2

junit version: 4.8.2

Android Developer Tools Build: v21.0.0-531062

**UPD:**
I have got following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams.<init>(AbstractHttpParams.java:5)
at org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams.<init>(BasicHttpParams.java:6)
at my.android.myprojectlib.api.HttpClientProxyImpl.<init>(HttpClientProxyImpl.java:27)
at my.android.myprojectlib.api.HttpMethodExecutorImpl.<init>(HttpMethodExecutorImpl.java:28)
at my.android.myprojectlib.api.HttpMethodExecutorFactory.getHttpMethodExecutor(HttpMethodExecutorFactory.java:21)
at my.android.myprojectlib.api.WMClientImpl.<init>(WMClientImpl.java:66)
at my.android.myprojectlib.api.AbstractWMLibTest.setUp(AbstractWMLibTest.java:31)
```

**UPD2:** Runtime classpath and build classpath are the same.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/java-json.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/commons-codec-1.6.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/fluent-hc-4.2.5.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/httpclient-4.2.5.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/httpcore-4.2.4.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/httpcomponents/httpmime-4.2.5.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProjectLibJavaTest/lib/httpcomponents/javadoc.zip!/javadoc"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/MyProjectLib"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Probably a classpath error, some stub implementation cannot be found by the runtime. Include the full stacktrace please.

Comment: It could be some incompatibility between Android and Apache libraries. `AbstractHttpParams` and `BasicHttpParams` have been deprecated since 4.3. It could therefore even depend on the order of the libraries in the class path. Android has the nasty habit of shipping stripped libraries...

Comment: @owI was playing a lot with order of the libraries - it does not have any impact.

Comment: I think you are exporting the Android stub libraries that ship with the SDK to the emulator or Android device. Those are [not implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247502/using-android-jar-in-java-project-runtimeexception-stub). The Ant file is probably generated using the build path instead of the runtime path - and those can be different.

Comment: But when I run tests using "Run as -> junit test" in Eclipce, it also should export the Android stub libraries? Because, I think, classspathes and dependences are the same when using ant.

Comment: Runtime configurations can be different from the build path. So if they use different libraries or not all libraries are exported then there may be differences. The only way to be sure is to check the runtime configuration against the build path.

Comment: Check order of your jars files in eclipse vs when running through ANT, hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when the `android.jar` is referenced before the `junit.jar` in the classpath.

In your `build.xml`, the order seems correct, but you specified the id with a space in it:

```
<path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
```

You should use ids without spaces or other special characters (.-_ are ok, though).

The stacktrace in your UPD1 shows no junit, which is another indication for a missing lib.