# Why getJSONObject() method's source code is "hidden"?

Tags: android, json, exception, architecture

I was wondering why the following happens:

[image]

---

1) Why the source code of this method is hidden? (Even If I'm debugging I cannot see a thing)

2) Why the writers/programmers of this library decided to do something like this?(Does it have any benefits)

3) Not only have I seen this happening in this library but also in other one. Why do they do that? What's its purpose?

Comment: If you look at the top of the editior there should be an option to download the source

Comment: @teh_raab So if you haven't downloaded them, the Android Studio shows them like this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247502/using-android-jar-in-java-project-runtimeexception-stub https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982631/error-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub-in-android-with-fitnesse-testing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913574/meaning-of-runtimeexceptionstub-in-android

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos correct.  CommonsWare has provided some links that explain this further.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you a lot.