# I can't create an instance of JSONObject

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

```java
public String prepareParam(HashMap<String, String> params) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
    return json.toString();
}
```

According to [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#public-constructors), a constructor with `Map<String, String>` is available. However, I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:87)
at com.example.spc.utils.JSONPararmeterPrepareStaregy.prepareParam(JSONParameters.java:12)
```

Comment: pls. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247502/using-android-jar-in-java-project-runtimeexception-stub/7247564

Comment: If you wish seeing the exception you should wrap inside `try catch` block.

Comment: thanks @JavaMan it must be that

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you pass something wrong to `prepareParam`. Trivial junit test works fine:

```
public class JSONObjectTest {
    public String prepareParam(Map<String, String> params) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Test public void test(){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        String str = prepareParam(map);
        assertEquals("error", "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}", str);
    }
}
```

BTW: It would be better if `prepareParam` accept `Map<String, String>` like `JSONObject` ctor does.